# Android get parent id in multi context menu

Tags: android, android-widget

in my code i have to listener to have multi context menu as :

```
    Button btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn1);  

    Button edit_text1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);  
    registerForContextMenu( edit_text1 );
```

now in `onContextItemSelected` i want to get witch widgets must be text to change. for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long buttonId = info.id;
    switch ( item.getItemId () ){
        case 1:
            /* IF USER REQUEST CONTEXT MENU ON btn1  */
            btn1.setText( "OK" );
            /* IF USER REQUEST CONTEXT MENU ON edit_text1 */
            edit_text1.setText( "" );
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

unfortunately i get `java.lang.NullPointerException` error for `info.id`

**UPDATE POST**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle( R.string.choose_selection );
    view_id = v.getId();
    menu.add(0, view_id, 0, getResources ().getString ( R.string.clear ) );
    menu.add(0, view_id, 0, getResources ().getString ( R.string.cut ) );
    menu.add(0, view_id, 0, getResources ().getString ( R.string.copy ) );
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.e("itemID  ", item.getItemId ()+"");
    Log.e("view_id ", view_id+"");
    switch ( item.getItemId () ){
        case 1:
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

in `onContextItemSelected` , `item.getItemId ()` and `view_id` are same, after get parent context menu how to get menu item id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getMenuInfo()` method will return null in this case, as those Views are not attaching any extra info to the menu. This is probably saving you from a `ClassCastException`, since those Views are not child Views of an AdapterView.

Make `buttonId` a class member of your Activity, and retrieve it from the View passed into the `onCreateContextMenu()` method.

```
private int buttonId;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    buttonId = v.getId();
    ...
}
```

Comment: They're the same because you're setting all the `itemId`s to `view_id`. Don't do that.